# Method to conditionally return the sum of every Nth object's property in a Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, enums

I am building a method to apply a "free" discount to an arraylist called parcels which is of type `Parcel`. A discount should be applied on every 4th "small" parcel - example below. A `Parcel` object has properties such as cost (a double) and type which is of `ParcelType`. `ParcelType` is an `Enum` (small, medium, large, xl).

Below is my method to apply the discount which is defined within a class called `Order`. I want the method to sum the cost of each parcel which is eligible for discount and return that sum so i can remove it from the order total in another method. I think part of my problem is I may need to map or forEach the parcels arraylist to get access to the parcel? Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
public double smallParcelDiscount(ArrayList<Parcel> parcels){

        for (int i = 0; i < parcels.size(); i ++) {

            if (parcel % 4 == 0 && parcels.ParcelType.SMALL){
// sum the cost of each eligible small parcel i.e if there are 2 small 
//parcels valid for discount in an order containing 8 small parcels
// return the sum so that it can be subtracted from the total cost of an order
            }
        }
    }
```

**Parcel class constructor:**

```
public class Parcel {

    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double height;
    private ParcelType type;
    private double cost;
    private double weight;

    public Parcel(double length, double width, double height, ParcelType type, double cost, double weight) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.type = type;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
```

**ParcelType Enum:**

```
public enum ParcelType {
    SMALL(1),
    MEDIUM(3),
    LARGE(6),
    XL(10),
    HEAVY(50);

    private final double weightLimit;

    ParcelType(double weightLimit){
        this.weightLimit = weightLimit;
    }

    public double getWeightLimit(){
        return weightLimit;
    }

}
```

**Order class constructor**:

```
public class Order {

    private ArrayList<Parcel> parcels;
    private Boolean speedyShipping;


    public Order() {
        this.parcels = new ArrayList<>();
        this.speedyShipping = false;
    }
```

Comment: `&& parcels[i].type == .ParcelType.SMALL`

Comment: Couldn’t you just use a stream with a filter to get all small parcels and then use the filtered list to get the value / costs of each fourth Parcel?

Comment: @DanielWosch could you provide an implementation example in context? I am using a stream currently to calculate the overall cost of the order but with a map to map the doubles of each cost property to a sum.

Comment: Im on my mobile phone which makes posting some Code little bit complicated. See the answer below which goes in this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public double smallParcelDiscount(ArrayList<Parcel> parcels) {
    return IntStream.range(0, parcels.size())
            .filter(n -> (n + 1) % 4 == 0) //take every fourth parcel one based
            .mapToObj(parcels::get)
            .filter(parcel -> ParcelType.SMALL.equals(parcel.getType()))
            .mapToDouble(Parcel::getCost)
            .sum();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t the filter by parcel type happen before the filter by 4th?

Comment: This works. Before I accept this answer can you please modify `parcel.type` and `parcel.cost` to the respective getters? You cannot access parcel directly like this because the properties are private. Getters need to be invoked. Also Daniel is correct I think but I can't explain why this works. I want to filter out every 4th and make it free if it's type is SMALL. Thanks for your contribution. Once you amend I will accept this response. Feel free to provide any further explanation of your solution or additional code comments.

Comment: I realise I didn't provide the getters in my code example above. They are simply `getCost()` and `getType()`.

Comment: @loco i edited the answer and used the getters

Comment: @DanielWosch it depends wether you want a discount every 4th small parcel or every 4th parcel that is small

Comment: Sure. Than I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: I tested your solution with a unit test and swapped out the 4th small parcel for a medium and it worked so I believe your implementation is what i'm looking for. Thanks for your time.